# Is it possible to leave the outer space area?

Tags: hungry-shark-evolution

In Hungry Shark Evolution, after you take the tiger shark to the pink outer space sea area, is it possible to return to the normal sea? I see the portal and it looks active but I don't know how to enter it. I tried jumping, sitting there, etc.

[image]

Usually I just run out of things to eat then die.